# Set custom font to web browser control, windows phone 7/ 7.5

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control, custom-font

For my windows phone application i need to load a web page(a blog post). So i used a web browser control and set url. Then i needed to add custom font for the web page content. I'm stuck with it. I tried adding "FontFamily" property to the web browser control, but nothing happened. Anybody knows how to do this.

Comment: Could you please clarify whether you want to apply a real custom font (EOT, TTF/OTF) or just use different one?

Comment: Then I totally agree with answers below. BTW, WP8 IE10 supports custom fonts - tried myself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to apply custom font to web browser content WP7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119852/how-to-apply-custom-font-to-web-browser-content-wp7)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internet Explorer on Windows Phone 7 and 7.5 does not support custom fonts such as EOT, TTF/OTF and WOFF fonts.

Source on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff462082%28v=vs.92%29.aspx):

> Unsupported Features in Internet Explorer Mobile:
>   ...
>   Downloadable fonts such as EOT, TTF/OTF and WOFF fonts

Maybe you should download the blog post content and display it in a Silverlight control like the [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.windows.controls.richtextbox%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I tried using RichTextBox. http://htmltorichtextbox.codeplex.com/ this is one way i tried. But it gives me "Could not load type 'BF.SL.HtmlToRichTextBox' from assembly 'BF.SL.HtmlToRichTextBox, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'." error. Do you know how to fix this or any other code sample parsing html to richtextbox?

Answer (score 1):

The list of fonts supported by the Windows Phone IE browser [can be found here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/iemobile/archive/2010/11/10/supported-fonts-on-ie-for-windows-phone-7.aspx). These are the only fonts available to you, there is not way to specify or load different fonts. The font used to render the page is dictated by the HTML / CSS, not the `FontFamily` property of the `WebBrowser` control.