# how to apply custom font to web browser content WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, webbrowser-control, font-family

Am developing simple app for learning **webBrowser** concept in Windows phone. My aim is to display the content in Telugu(Indian language) in my WP7. that web application is displaying Telugu content only

my MainPage.xaml.cs code is :

```
private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.Navigate(new Uri("http://www.eenadu.net", UriKind.Absolute));
    }
```

in MainPage.xaml file

```
<phone:WebBrowser HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,92,0,0" Name="webBrowser1"
 VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="575" Width="468" FontFamily="Fonts/eenadu.ttf#Eenadu"  />
```

and i have included that .ttf file in my project under Fonts folder and assigned Build Action = 'Content'

Am able to call the URL but it displaying unreadable characters.

is there any other way to apply custom font to web browser control?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Windows phone supports web fonts.  However, they cannot be embedded in the XAP.  Suggested workaround is to host the fonts on a remote server and perhaps use AppCache to keep the font files locally on the device.

Comment: yes that font hosted in server and also getting expected font in android phone, how can we use AppCache (Isolated storage) can you please give me any example :)

Comment: I'll work up a sample.  Crushed right now but will work on it later in the week.

Comment: Like #2 in my list.  ping me again Wednesday or so.

Answer (score 0):

No need to host from remote server, you can use local font embedded CSS and inject to browser control.

(1.) Create the CSS with embedded font

```
body, a, p, span, div, textarea {
        font-family: MyCustomFont;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: MyCustomFont;
    src: url(data:application/x-font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,d09GRgABAXXXXXXXXXXX......) format('woff');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

(2.) Inject jQuery and CSS at WebView_NavigationCompleted method

```
 private async void MyWebView_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
 {
    // Inject jQuery file which located at local
    StorageFile jquery = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///JavaScripts\\jquery-1.10.2.min.js"));
        string jquery_string = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(jquery);
        await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { jquery_string });


    // Inject custom font embedded CSS 
    StorageFile myfontcss = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///CSS\\mycustomfont.css"));
            string myfontcss_string = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(myfontcss);

            myfontcss_string = myfontcss_string.Replace("\n", "").Replace("\t", ""); //.Replace("'", "&#39;").Replace("\"", "&#34;");
            string cssRef = "$(\"<style id='myfont' type='text/css'>" + myfontcss_string + "</style>\").appendTo('head');";

            await MyWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", new string[] { cssRef });

 }
```